# Ubuntu Gaming Question - Poor Performance

Tags: drivers, games, performance

So this is sort of a hardware question relating to the performance of games on my laptop. I am trying to play Counter Strike: Global Offensive (Click here for [required hardware](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=2672043)), and am facing sever difficulties- the game runs at 4-6 FPS!

I can run this game on XP/Vista/7 and 8 without a care in the world, so I do believe the issue here lies within the system settings of Ubuntu (and how it uses the hardware) or the actual gaming settings, trouble is I am not sure what. Side note: Counter Strike: Global Offensive can run natively off Linux.

I first did some network tests just to ensure there was no major "lag"- all was fine in this aspect. I then went on to look into the resource usage of the computer and noted the following:

[image: Resource Monitor]

It is with this I believe the hardware suffices for my needs, but that does not help me identify why the system is running poorly. I do have a few peripherals on my laptop (Razer Keyboard/Mouse and Headphone and cooler dock) but I honestly cannot find the cause for this.

Can someone advise me if they have any issues with games, or if there are any tools that can help me look into this? I will update this question as the time goes on to try and improve the info provided. Please see below a quick breakdown of my hardware.

Side Note (2): I have not looked into the drivers for my hardware, what would be the easiest way to confirm they are running the best possible solution?

**Hardware**

```
System:    Host: nancarrow-laptop Kernel: 3.13.0-45-generic x86_64 (64 bit, gcc: 4.8.2) 
           Desktop: Gnome Distro: Ubuntu 14.04 trusty

Machine:   System: TOSHIBA (portable) product: Satellite U50D-A version: PSKPSA-018023
           Mobo: TOSHIBA model: ZEMAE version: 1.00 Bios: TOSHIBA version: 1.30 date: 11/18/2013

CPU:       Quad core AMD A6-5200 APU with Radeon HD Graphics (-MCP-) cache: 8192 KB flags: (lm nx sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 sse4a ssse3 svm) bmips: 15970.4 
           Clock Speeds: 1: 800.00 MHz 2: 1000.00 MHz 3: 1600.00 MHz 4: 800.00 MHz

Graphics:  Card: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD/ATI] Kabini [Radeon HD 8400] bus-ID: 00:01.0 
           X.Org: 1.15.1 drivers: ati,radeon (unloaded: fbdev,vesa) Resolution: 1366x768@60.0hz 
           GLX Renderer: Gallium 0.4 on AMD KABINI GLX Version: 3.0 Mesa 10.1.3 Direct Rendering: Yes

Audio:     Card-1: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] FCH Azalia Controller driver: snd_hda_intel bus-ID: 00:14.2 

          Card-2: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD/ATI] Device 9840 driver: snd_hda_intel bus-ID: 00:01.1 

           Sound: Advanced Linux Sound Architecture ver: k3.13.0-45-generic

Network:   Card-1: Realtek RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller 
           driver: r8169 ver: 2.3LK-NAPI port: e000 bus-ID: 01:00.0
           IF: eth0 state: up speed: 100 Mbps duplex: full mac: 20:1a:06:7b:de:37
           Card-2: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9565 / AR9565 

Wireless Network Adapter driver: ath9k bus-ID: 02:00.0

           IF: wlan0 state: down mac: a4:db:30:16:2a:81

Drives:    HDD Total Size: 256.1GB (6.9% used) 1: id: /dev/sda model: Crucial_CT256MX1 size: 256.1GB temp: 38C 

Partition: ID: / size: 69G used: 4.8G (8%) fs: ext4 ID: /home size: 102G used: 12G (13%) fs: ext4 

           ID: swap-1 size: 25.00GB used: 0.00GB (0%) fs: swap 

RAID:      No RAID devices detected - /proc/mdstat and md_mod kernel raid module present

Sensors:   System Temperatures: cpu: 61.8C mobo: N/A gpu: 61.0 
           Fan Speeds (in rpm): cpu: N/A 

Info:      Processes: 194 Uptime: 47 min Memory: 1786.4/15411.9MB Runlevel: 2 Gcc sys: 4.8.2 
           Client: Shell (bash 4.3.11) inxi: 1.9.17
```

As requested, I have performed additional testing:

```
360 GLXFBConfigs:
    visual  x   bf lv rg d st  colorbuffer  sr ax dp st accumbuffer  ms  cav
  id dep cl sp  sz l  ci b ro  r  g  b  a F gb bf th cl  r  g  b  a ns b eat
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
0x061 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x062 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 Slow
0x063 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x064 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 Slow
0x065 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x066 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 Slow
0x067 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 16  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x068 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 16  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 Slow
0x069 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 16  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x06a 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 16  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 Slow
0x06b 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 16  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x06c 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 16  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 Slow
0x06d 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x06e 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 Slow
0x06f 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x070 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 Slow
0x071 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x072 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 Slow
0x073 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x074 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 Slow
0x075 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x076 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 Slow
0x077 32 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x078 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 Slow
0x079 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  2 1 None
0x07a 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  4 1 None
0x07b 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  8 1 None
0x07c 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  2 1 None
0x07d 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  4 1 None
0x07e 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  8 1 None
0x07f 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  2 1 None
0x080 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  4 1 None
0x081 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  8 1 None
0x082 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 16  0  0  0  0  0  2 1 None
0x083 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 16  0  0  0  0  0  4 1 None
0x084 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 16  0  0  0  0  0  8 1 None
0x085 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 16  0  0  0  0  0  2 1 None
0x086 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 16  0  0  0  0  0  4 1 None
0x087 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 16  0  0  0  0  0  8 1 None
0x088 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 16  0  0  0  0  0  2 1 None
0x089 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 16  0  0  0  0  0  4 1 None
0x08a 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 16  0  0  0  0  0  8 1 None
0x08b 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  0  0  0  0  0  2 1 None
0x08c 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  0  0  0  0  0  4 1 None
0x08d 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  0  0  0  0  0  8 1 None
0x08e 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  0  0  0  0  0  2 1 None
0x08f 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  0  0  0  0  0  4 1 None
0x090 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  0  0  0  0  0  8 1 None
0x091 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  0  0  0  0  0  2 1 None
0x092 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  0  0  0  0  0  4 1 None
0x093 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  0  0  0  0  0  8 1 None
0x094 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  2 1 None
0x095 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  4 1 None
0x096 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  8 1 None
0x097 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  2 1 None
0x098 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  4 1 None
0x099 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  8 1 None
0x09a 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  2 1 None
0x09b 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  4 1 None
0x09c 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  8 1 None
0x09d 24 tc  0  24  0 r  . .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x09e 24 tc  0  24  0 r  . .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0  0  0 16 16 16  0  0 0 Slow
0x09f 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0a0 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0  0  0 16 16 16  0  0 0 Slow
0x0a1 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0a2 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0  0  0 16 16 16  0  0 0 Slow
0x0a3 24 tc  0  24  0 r  . .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 16  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0a4 24 tc  0  24  0 r  . .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 16  0 16 16 16  0  0 0 Slow
0x0a5 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 16  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0a6 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 16  0 16 16 16  0  0 0 Slow
0x0a7 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 16  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0a8 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 16  0 16 16 16  0  0 0 Slow
0x0a9 24 tc  0  24  0 r  . .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0aa 24 tc  0  24  0 r  . .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  0 16 16 16  0  0 0 Slow
0x0ab 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0ac 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  0 16 16 16  0  0 0 Slow
0x0ad 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0ae 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  0 16 16 16  0  0 0 Slow
0x0af 24 tc  0  24  0 r  . .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0b0 24 tc  0  24  0 r  . .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8 16 16 16  0  0 0 Slow
0x0b1 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0b2 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8 16 16 16  0  0 0 Slow
0x0b3 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0b4 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8 16 16 16  0  0 0 Slow
0x0b5 24 tc  0  24  0 r  . .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  2 1 None
```

Comment: Please inclue a `glxinfo` output, though the problem will be the Gallium driver

Comment: @meskobalazs I have added in the required information into the question as requested, however had to cut down more than 70% to fit the word limit. Please let me know if this suffices.

Comment: Well, sorry that I haven't said, I was mostly interested in the first about 20 lines.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### The reason of the poor performance

The problem will be this:

```
 GLX Renderer: Gallium 0.4 on AMD KABINI GLX Version: 3.0 Mesa 10.1.3
```

Unfortunately the KABINI APUs still have quite poor open source driver support, so I suggest installing the proprietry `fglrx`driver, which yields better 3D support. Gallium is the open source radeon driver, if this was not clear.

Ps.: I am using an A4-5000M KABINI APU, so I am speaking from experience.

#### Installing the drivers in Ubuntu

If you are using Ubuntu, you should just let `jockey` do its thing and do not hassle with manual installation. Using the latest drivers manually has advantages, but then you have to manage it yourself, no help by the Ubuntu repositories. You should only tread on this path, if you are absolutely sure, that you want this, *here be dragons* :)

Jockey is also known as [Additional Drivers](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/jockey-gtk/) . You just simply need to run it, select the (recommended) AMD driver, click ok, and restart. And now you are running `fglrx`.

Comment: Hello. I am fairly new to this so will need to review the install and perform, most likely over the weekend. I will probably follow this guide (http://bit.ly/16k12hc) but if you could advise me how to approach this correctly I would be appreciative. Once I perform this and all works I will mark your answer as correct.

Comment: Adding tips to my answer

Comment: @MichaelNancarrow I'd avoid tutorials for other distributions unless you *really* know what you're doing.

Comment: @meskobalazs Thank you! I have performed as requested and now get anywhere from 12-33 FPS per second. It's still quite buggy and hard to play, but it is far better than what it was. Thank you for your prompt assistance. If you are aware of any other improvements that could be made, please let me know.

Comment: The "Additional drivers" is a rather nice way of handling the "How to choose which driver you want" problem.